# Service Fabric with Java on Windows

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to create the SF using java on a windows environment? What happens with the cluster provisioned on Azure? Does it contain the JVM? I've been trying to create a SF using eclipse in my windows environment where I also have VS 2015 and both SF SDKs but it does work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SF Windows environment doesnt support Java based Sateless/Stateful , Reliable Actor services. It is supported only in Linux (ubuntu 16.0 LTS) 
But you could run it as Guest executable on Windows.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in Windows. Do you have any example for guest executable on windows to run java program. if yes please share.i am fine with VS2017 or Visual code